# How do I get Tire to filter by current_team?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am implementing Elasticsearch using Tire (and Ryan Bates' railscasts) as a site-wide search.   It searches across multiple models.  I would like for it to filter by current_team.  I have at least two problems:

1) hard-coding the filter to 'team 2' brings back no results.  In the particular query I was running, I should get two. I've tried a variety of formats of the number, the team, etc.  Nothing I've tried works.

2) I don't know how to pass the team_id to the filter as a variable.  I tried sending it like this: **__**.search(params, team), but that resulted in no query results (which led me to hard code the team id as in #1)

I've spent about 6 hours so far on this on Google.  The closest thing I got to was Karmi's response to a similar question on github which basically said, 'read the manual, its there.'  :)  I've read it, and being a newby, I'm still lost.

Here is the code, as it stands now.

application.html.erb

```
<bunch of code>

<%= form_tag searches_path, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<bunch of code>
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address_1, :address_2, :city, :first_name, :last_name, :state, :zip, :team_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :appointments

  before_save :update_name 

  def update_name
    self.name = [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end

  #for elastic search
  include Tire::Model::Search 
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do 
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      filter :term, :team_id => ['2']
    end
  end  
end
```

searches_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    current_team = :current_team
    @contacts = Contact.search(params)
    @properties = Property.search(params)
   # @events = Event.search(params[:query], load: true)
  end
  def show

  end

end
```

Search: index.html.erb:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Search Results</h1>

  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>

<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= contact.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= contact.team_id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>


  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address 1</th>
  </tr>

<% @properties.each do |property| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= property.name %></td>
    <td><%= property.address_1 %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>



</div>
```

Note that there is a similar search function in the Properties controller.  I'm just trying to get Contacts to work for now.

curl command requested below produces:

Comment: Did you make sure that you imported existing records into ES?

Comment: Yes...when I comment out the filter line, the search field works as expected.

Comment: Would you please add the output of this command `curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/contacts/_search"`

Comment: it just sits there with a ">"

Comment: You sure you didn't forget the quote on the end or ES server is running?

Comment: ok...picky picky ;)  here we go: ... posting it in the original question because it is too long for a comment

Comment: ok...reading through that list above, I see that there are no team_id's with a value of 2 in the index (its in the database because I manually edited the table to show a value of 2 in a couple records.  Let me reindex and retry all of this

Comment: so now, filter :term, :team_id => '2' works.  I tried a few of the ways I'd tried before to pass the current_team, and that's not working.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass current_team value via params and keep the current search method signature.
For example, in your controller:

```
def index
  params[:current_team] = current_team # method that returns current team ID, are you using devise?
  @contacts = Contact.search(params)
  @properties = Property.search(params)
  # @events = Event.search(params[:query], load: true)
end
```

and in your model:

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(load: true) do 
    query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
    filter :term, params[:current_team] if params[:current_team].present?
  end
end
```

Comment: I probably spent an hour yesterday (before I posted this question) trying to figure out how to put this into params.  Thanks!